# How to rewind next-search start position by 1?

Tags: perl, regex-lookarounds

How can I rewind the start of the next search position by 1?  For example, suppose I want to match all digits between `#`. The following will give me only **odd** numbers.

```
my $data="#1#2#3#4#";

while ( $data =~ /#(\d)#/g ) {
  print $1, "\n";
}
```

But if I could rewind the start of the next position by 1, I would get both even and odd numbers.

This doesn't work: `pos() = pos() - 1;`

I know I can accomplish this using `split`. But this doesn't answer my question.

```
for (split /#/, $data) {
  print $_, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `pos()` on `$_`, instead of `$data`

From [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)

> Returns the offset of where the last m//g search left off for the variable in question ($_ is used when the variable is not specified)

So,

```
pos($data) = pos($data) - 1;
```

Answer (score 12):

One approach is to use a [look-ahead assertion](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlre.pod#Look-Around-Assertions):

```
while ( $data =~ /#(\d)(?=#)/g ) {
  print $1, "\n";
}
```

The characters in the look-ahead assertion are not part of the matched expression and do not update `pos()` past the `\d` part of the regular expression.

More demos:

```
say "#1#2#3#4#" =~ /#(\d)/g;          #  1234
say "#1#2#3#4"  =~ /#(\d)/g;          #  1234
say "#1#2#3#4#" =~ /#(\d)(?=#)/g;     #  1234
say "#1#2#3#4"  =~ /#(\d)(?=#)/g;     #  123
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question as posed, it is a better solution to what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: I am constantly amazed that people can read this gibberish. That top while loop - not a clue WTF it does.

Comment: Luckily you're in the right place as SO users can give you answers to all kind of programming questions.

Comment: @Alec Teal, Chinese appears to be gibberish to someone who only knows English, but it's not, and it's rude to say it is. Rather than proudly announcing your ignorance, perhaps you should seek education? `/.../` matches the regex pattern within against the variable bound by the `=~` operator (`$data`, in this case). In scalar context (as it is here), it returns true if there is match. In scalar context, the `g` option causes the position at which the match ended to be saved as the starting position of the next attempt.

Comment: A better explanation of look-ahead assertions can be found at https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html